# Order of query execution

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I have a query of the basic structure

```
with cte1 as (Select *query on tbl1*)
,cte2 as (select *query on tbl1*
      Exception join cte1 )

Select * from cte1
union all
Select * from cte2
```

And I really have no idea whether I can be confident this will behave as expected - each of ctes produce similar rows, but would have different logic - I want cte1 to pass through the table with its logic, then cte2 to review the same table again, after cte1 has picked all the records that apply to it - will this work?

Edit: Ok, I have created some data and outlined where I am concerned. I am not sure how to interpret philipxy's response with the above - I can understand from his response what to expect from cte1, but I do not fully understand what cte2 would be - does cte1 get "declared" before cte2, so that their values are locked in once the query begins?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to see the access plan of the query?

Comment: Please edit your question to trace through an example showing the actions that you are afraid might happen. Your message does not say enough about it for us to know what you mean, ie whether what you mean is how SQL works.

Comment: I have edited with my concerns, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused about the interpretation of SQL queries. Maybe all queries, or maybe just CTE queries, or maybe just recursive CTE queries.

The value of a relational query is based on names representing values (that are tables) and on the value of an expression being calculated from those values to give other values.

An update then causes the new current value of a base table, ie the value associated with a base table name, to be the value calculated by the query. SQL queries describe how updated rows in terms of input rows, but all rows are updated at once.

A base table name stands for its value before the query is executed. A recursively defined CTE name is one that is used in its own definition. That describes a loop which when executed gives a new value for the CTE name in every iteration. (You didn't do that here.) Otherwise a CTE name stands for the value given to it when it was introduced.

Since this CTE query isn't recursive, you can just take the base table names and CTE names as standing for their values. So your CTE names only ever have one value, and when you SELECT from a named (base or CTE) table it doesn't affect its value.

Comment: Does that mean the order of the decision of current value is the order I declare the ctes? cte1 is locked in, then cte2 is locked in based on the locked in values of cte1?
Also, I was trying to do an insert from table B into table A, while referencing table A - how might that behave? Something like:
`Insert into A select * from B join A`
Whenever I've been in a situation I needed to do this, it would be on some sequential key, say insert the key=1, then key=2 by seeing the 1s are already in, but I was worried that the query would see the new 2s inserted before it finished the 1s

Comment: I'd like to say yes or no, but you are writing in strange terms. Only recursively defined CTE table name definitions define a loop; otherwise a table name only has one value in a SELECT, and an UPDATE changes all rows at once. It's like where `s1 = 'x' + s; s2 = s1 + s` has only has one value each for string s, s1 & s2 and strings are updated all characters at once. See my updated answer. PS Play with http://www.sqlfiddle.com.

Comment: @scott.se If the order wasn't meaningful, you could reverse the specs for `cte1` and `cte2`. Since cte2 makes reference to cte1, it should immediately become clear if order matters. But it's irrelevant anyway. The same values are going to be SELECTed no matter which way it works. There's nothing here that changes any rows.